# Stripping invalid characters from a PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

We're getting PDFs from a vendor that have 58,000+ null characters following the legal end of the document %%EOF. We're working with the vendor to see if they can correct it, but I want to get ahead of the issue in case they can't.

Using PHP (or classic ASP, though I doubt *that's* possible) I want to

- find the EOF marker
- strip anything after
- and resave the file as a valid PDF.

I've not worked with binary files before and have only a vague idea of where to even start.

Comment: maybe php is not the best tool here: `awk ' /^%EOF/ {print "%EOF"; exit} {print}' filename.pdf > newfilename.pdf`

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific: I'm on a windows server running IIS 7.5/8, and the task is one small part of a much larger process. PHP may not be the best tool, but it's the one I've got.